# codeigniter scalable folder structure

Tags: codeigniter, scalability, structure

I've use symfony and now using codeigniter is there any folder structure 
that can be used in scalable applications similar to symfony.

I want to make an application that will be divided in sub-apps and the sub-apps
will have their own modules.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is called HMVC (Hierarchical Model View Controller). This means that an application is split up into *modules* (or as you described them, rather accurately, "sub-apps"). Sadly CodeIgniter does not support HMVC unmodified, however there is a [drop-in extension for CodeIgniter which allows you to use a HMVC architecture](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home). [Thanks Wesley]

Alternatively you can use a fork of CodeIgniter which is specifically designed for HMVC called [Kohana Framework](http://kohanaframework.org/). The project was originally a fork but has now changed massively and is barely recognisable from the original CI project.

Comment: +1, I was typing a bit lazily as you posted this. Just want to point out that HMVC is not a Codeigniter fork or "version" or standalone, but rather a drop-in solution that should work *with* any version of CI (at least 2.x). There is no modification of source code, but rather extensions of it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as modules go, the go-to solution for CI is the HMVC package:

https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home

This is a "drop-in" solution; very easy to install, has been around for quite a long time, and is actively maintained.

Since Codeigniter tries to stay lightweight, you'll find that a lot of important things you need, like Auth or ORMs, are not built in, and you have to use third party code.

A lot of solutions hosted here: http://getsparks.org/packages/browse/latest

And the wiki: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/